# How to assign pins to natural type of ports in Xilinx

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

How can I assign `natural` types of ports to pins in XILINX UCF file?

```
Generic (
    nr_ro     : natural := 32
);            

Port (  
    clk_i     : in  STD_LOGIC;
    rst_i     : in  STD_LOGIC;
    sel1_i    : in  natural range 0 to nr_ro-1;
    sel2_i    : in  natural range 0 to nr_ro-1;
    bit_o     : out std_logic;
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the one place where you can't use type `natural` is top level ports, where they are mapped to physical device pins. This is because you need to connect each individual bit of the signal to its own pin, so you need some type that represents the signal as an array of bits.

My choice would be to convert to/from `natural` to `unsigned` for this purpose. The unsigned will have 5 bits to count from 0 to 31.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
...

Port (  
          sel1    : in unsigned(nr_bits-1 downto 0);
...

sel_1 <= to_unsigned(sel1_i,nr_bits);
...
```

And now you connect each bit of sel_1 to its own pin in the UCF file. In VHDL you can access individual bits `sel1(4)`, `sel1(0)` etc.

In the UCF file the syntax may be slightly different' `sel1_4` etc, refer to the UCF documentation to see how it numbers individual bits of a bus..

Comment: Doesn't IDE automatically convert `natural` to `std_logic_vector` when used in top level entity?

Comment: @Brian, Thanks for useful answer. Qui, I think no, IDE does not convert it automatically.